# For using google api is it necessary to install the google client libraries for using Oauth 2 in wordpress installation?

Tags: api, google, oauth

In a wordpress installation I am trying to fetch data from the search google console api.

Seems I need Oauth 2.0

Is there some short code that I can use without installing all the libraries with composer?

Cannot find code which does it without the libraries.

Comment: a shortcode would need all the libraries too, shortcodes are for embedding things inside post content by running some PHP code to generate output, they're not intended for other things such as loading libraries or OAuth2 implementations. You could build this without libraries in PHP but it would be very difficult and require some understanding of complex security stuff and cryptography, it would be significantly harder than having a library do it all for you

Comment: ah ok. so you say to go with the provided libraries. Btw I wanted to say some short code not shortcode :-D